# Is there a linguistic term for words that mean "not a member of a certain group"?

Tags: single-word-requests, linguistics

Is there a linguistic term for words that describe a group whose sole common characteristic is that the members are *not* members of a smaller, special group?

- civilian (not a soldier)
- Gentile (not Jewish)
- layperson (not clergy)
- [neurotypical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neurotypical) (not autistic, etc.)
- Muggle (not a wizard in the *Harry Potter* series)

Comment: The outsiders? The others?

Comment: All terms are linguistic in the sense of 'connected with a language'. And I don't see how the meta-language sense ('connected with linguistics') would apply here. You probably mean 'Is there a general term ...'.

Comment: Not what you're looking for probably, but these words all describe the *complement* of a particular group (from set theory). Perhaps "complementary?"

Answer (score 2):

**[Exclusive](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/exclusive)** (as in the opposite of inclusive).

Whenever you create a single, binary classification of a group, the word you use to name that group (i.e. soldiers, jews, clergy, autistics, wizards) is the inclusive. The word you use to describe everything else (civilians, gentiles, laypeople, neurotypical, Muggles) is the exclusive.

Inclusive vs. exclusive language is only relevant from the context of a small subset referring to the larger excluded whole. For example, only a soldier would call someone a civilian, and only a Jew would call someone a gentile. Civilians and gentiles simply do not think in those terms.

When you are talking about a binary classification where the perspective does not matter (e.g. male vs. female, introvert vs. extrovert, etc.) that's called **[Mutually exclusive](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/mutually-exclusive)**.